# Why logger doesn't write anything (python3)?

Tags: python, logging

All I want is to use logger for the program I am writing, and it is writing nothing in the log, here is the related code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import logging

class Excel2csv():
def __init__(self, input=None, output=None ):
    self.process_options(input, output)
    self.create_log_directory()
    self.config_logger()

def config_logger(self):
    logger = os.path.basename(__file__).split(".")[0]
    global logger_location
    logger_location = os.getcwd() + '/log/' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") + '.log'
    print("logger_location:" + logger_location)
    logging.basicConfig(filename=logger_location, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    self.logger = logging.getLogger(logger)
    self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def run(self):
    start_time = time.time()

    self.extract2csv()

    stop_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    elapsed_time = stop_time - start_time

    self.logger.info('=============================================================================================')
    self.logger.info('Report for the session')

    self.logger.info('Log location for this session: ' + logger_location)
    self.logger.info('Job/report processed by: ' + getpass.getuser() + ' on host: ' + socket.gethostname())
    self.logger.info('=============================================================================================')
    print('\nDone!')


def run_from_cmd():
    Excel2csv().run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Excel2csv().run()
```

The log file is generated but nothing is written to it.

It would be appreciated if someone can help me sort it out, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the level of output:

```
import logging    
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format="[%(levelname)s] [%(asctime)s] %(message)s",
                        datefmt="%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

When using a file, you can add:

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s] [%(asctime)s] %(message)s',"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "%")
fh = logging.FileHandler("log")
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
```